# BlueZ 5.23 How to Build btgatt-client Tool

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, gatt

There is a command line tool in the source of BlueZ 5.23 called btgatt-client. One of the command line parameters is "write-long-value". This is exactly what I need but after modifying the Makefile.tools file in the linked patch below, and running configure with the 'enable-tools' parameter, it does not get built alongside the other tools.

Has anyone built this tool or can anyone help me figure out how to build it? Thanks.

http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-bluetooth/msg52170.html

http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-bluetooth/msg52395.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't need to change any of the Makefiles. Just configure with --enable-experimental.

I'm on Bluez 5.24. But I assume that hasn't changed.